# Errors when searching for special characters in awk

Tags: awk

How can I search for a pattern in `awk` if the text contains special characters?

```
billinAddress ||
```

when I search, it is showing an error on pipe sign `||`.  How can I search for the pipe sign `||` in awk?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to escape them using `\`. So, instead of writing `billinAddress ||`, you need to write `billinAddress \|\|`.

For example, you can search for your pattern using:

```
awk '/billinAddress \|\|/{ print $0 }' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ echo 'billinAddress ||' | awk '/\|\|/{ print $0 }'
billinAddress ||
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ echo 'billinAddress' | awk '/\|\|/{ print $0 }'
```